# How to update a value of a particular row which satisfies a condition inside the SELECT statement in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have tables like "Bed" and "PatientRecord". I want to allocate an empty bed to a patient (i.e bID from Bed table with status ="Available") then change that bID status to "Occupied". Please help with this. The following is my current query but i am unsure how to proceed.

```
update Patient_Record 
set b_ID = (select top 1 b_ID from bed where Status_Avai_Occ = 'Available')
/*i want to change the status of this b_ID to "Occupied"*/
where Admission_Type = 'In Patient'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would update all PatientRecords with Admission_Type = `In Patient`

I'm not sure if I fully understand your structure but you could do this:

```
DECLARE @AvailableBID INT
SELECT TOP 1 @AvailableBID = b_ID FROM bed WHERE Status_Avai_Occ = 'Available'

UPDATE Patient_Record 
SET b_ID = @AvailableBID
WHERE Admission_Type = 'In Patient'

UPDATE bed
SET Status_Avai_occ = 'Occupied'
WHERE b_ID = @AvailableBid
```

Note this will still update all Patient_records with Admission_Type In Patient.  You will need to apply an additional filter, i.e. the row number.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa26d/9

**Edit from the comments**

```
DECLARE @AvailableBID INT
DECLARE @AvailablePatientRecord INT

SELECT TOP 1 @AvailableBID = b_ID FROM bed WHERE Status_Avai_Occ = 'Available'
SELECT TOP 1 @AvailablePatientRecord  = PatientRecordId FROM Patient_Record WHERE Admission_Type = 'In Patient'

UPDATE Patient_Record 
SET b_ID = @AvailableBID
WHERE PatientRecordId = @AvailablePatientRecord

UPDATE bed
SET Status_Avai_occ = 'Occupied'
WHERE b_ID = @AvailableBid
```

Note: you will have to ensure you have a PatientRecordId in your Patient_Record table

Comment: I think the request really was to make it a set-based operation, allocating *different* beds to all in patients

Comment: and if you wrapped it in a transaction it would be either all done or all undone by the RDBMS

Comment: @DavidHedlund ah okay - I'll let the OP clarify this and adjust.  Thanks.

Comment: my question was like what David mentioned. i want to allocate different "Available" beds to the in patients which means after every allocation of an "Available" bed i want to change the status immediately to "Occupied" so that i dont keep allocating the same bed to all the patients.....sorry if the question was confusing...pls help with this...thnks in advance

Comment: @Gayu - have you tried my query. It should do what you require.  Each time you run it, it will take the TOP b_ID from bed where the code is Available.  It will then update the status code to Occupied, therefore when the query is reran it will get an available bed.

Comment: @Darren- yes i have. but i am getting an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword Top"

Comment: @Darren - i rerun the query but only my Bed table status gets updated, the Patient_Record table is not updated...pls help

Comment: @Gayu - does the Patient_Record table have any entries with Admission_Type = 'In Patient'?

Comment: @Darren - yes it does. around 231 rows

Comment: @Gayu - the query should work fine. How many rows are affected when you run the query? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @Darren - i get no error messages. I only get the following
(0 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: @Darren - it works now but it updates the same value for all patients. is there a way to add different beds to different patients?

Comment: @Gayu - yes.  I mentioned that in my comments that it would update all records.  You need to add an additional filter using WHERE PatientRecordID = ID or SELECT the first entry like you have done from the BED table... I will adjust my answer.

Comment: @Darren - this works but it keeps allocating different beds to the same patient each time i runt the query. pls lemme knw what do i do to increment the inpatient id every time.i tried to add another condition to the existing query saying 
{PatientRecordId FROM Patient_Record WHERE Admission_Type = 'In Patient' and b_ID <>0 } but it doesnt work...sry to bother so much i am very new to sql

Comment: @Darren - i cant believe myself that i got this working by just adding an extra condition!!! its                                                {PatientRecordId FROM Patient_Record WHERE Admission_Type = 'In Patient' and b_ID =0 }                                                  Now i need to figure out how to do this automatically for 500 records without running the query 500 times :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason you are finding this difficult is because your design is flawed, but there isn't enough information to correct that. I'm not sure which patient you are trying to give a bed to, in below i've used the `@PatientIdToGiveBed` to specify that as in your example you will give all 'In Patient' the same bed. It's possible you will need to modify this to select the first 'In Patient' in the same way that the bed is selected.

The transaction needs to have an isolation level of `REPEATABLE READ` which will prevent two transactions from assigning the same bed, if you used the default `READ COMMITTED`, two transactions could select the same bed. This way a `READ LOCK` is held on the selected bed until the transaction is complete.

You can put the entire statement below into SSMS and run to test it.

```
DECLARE @Bed TABLE  (
    b_ID INT,
    Status_Avai_Occ VARCHAR(20)
)

DECLARE @Patient_Record TABLE (
    Id INT, 
    Name VARCHAR(10),
    b_ID INT
)

INSERT INTO @Bed VALUES (1, 'Available') 
INSERT INTO @Bed VALUES (2, 'Available') 
INSERT INTO @Bed VALUES (3, 'Available') 

INSERT INTO @Patient_Record VALUES (1, 'Adam', NULL) 
INSERT INTO @Patient_Record VALUES (2, 'Ben', NULL) 
INSERT INTO @Patient_Record VALUES (3, 'Charles', NULL) 

DECLARE @PatientIdToGiveBed INT = 1

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ 
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    DECLARE @Available_BID INT
    SELECT TOP 1 @Available_BID = b_ID FROM @BED WHERE Status_Avai_Occ = 'Available' ORDER BY b_ID

    IF @Available_BID IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        Print 'No Beds Available'
        COMMIT 
        RETURN 
    END 

    UPDATE @Patient_Record SET b_ID = @Available_BID WHERE Id = @PatientIdToGiveBed 
    UPDATE @Bed SET Status_Avai_Occ = 'Occupied' WHERE b_ID = @Available_BID 
COMMIT 

SELECT * FROM @Patient_Record
SELECT * FROM @Bed
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't allow you to update more than one table in a single UPDATE statement, however you can simply wrap the two updates in a single transaction, as follows:

```
DECLARE @b_ID INT
SELECT TOP 1 @b_ID = b_ID FROM bed WHERE Status_Avai_Occ = 'Available'

BEGIN TRAN Update_Patient

UPDATE  Patient_Record 
  SET   b_ID = @b_ID
  WHERE Admission_Type = 'In Patient' 

UPDATE  bed
  SET   Status_Avai_Occ = 'Occupied'
  WHERE (b_ID = @b_ID)

COMMIT TRAN Update_Patient
```

Comment: i tried this query but my Patient_Record doesn't get updated. Only the bed table gets updated :( pls help

Answer (score 2):

```
1. set variable "openBed" to available bed id
2. update bed with bed id = openBed to 'Occupied'
3. update patient_record set bed id = openBed where admission_type = 'in patient'
```

Note: the **3rd statement** will update every `In Patient` record in your `Patient_Record` table to the same bed id each time. In other words, every patient will be reassigned to the next available bed each time a new patient is admitted. That'll be a pretty crowded bed.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to run this across a set of patients at once, you need to first match up the beds, and then assign them, as there is no way in SQL Server to update two tables at once, so that your set-based select will yield a different bed_ID each time.

```
-- Set up some temp tables to hold data
DECLARE @availBeds table (num int identity(1,1), b_ID int)
DECLARE @inPatients table (num int identity(1,1), p_ID int)
DECLARE @patientBeds table (p_ID int, b_ID int)

-- Populate table of available beds only, giving them a unique incremental ID
INSERT INTO @availBeds SELECT b_ID FROM Bed WHERE status_avai_occ = 'Available'

-- Populate table of in patients without assigned beds only, giving them a unique incremental ID
INSERT INTO @inPatients SELECT p_ID FROM Patient_Record WHERE admission_type = 'In Patient' AND b_ID IS NULL

-- Join the two tables above based on their incremental ID's,
-- effectively matching up available beds with patients
INSERT INTO @patientBeds
    SELECT p.p_ID, b.b_ID FROM @inPatients p
    INNER JOIN @availBeds b ON b.num = p.num

-- Update Patient_Record with the new bed ID's
UPDATE p
SET p.b_ID = b.b_ID
FROM Patient_Record p
INNER JOIN @patientBeds b ON p.p_ID = b.p_ID

-- Set the Beds to Occupied
UPDATE Bed SET status_avai_occ = 'Occupied' WHERE b_ID IN (SELECT b_ID FROM @patientBeds)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1af8/4)

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot update 2 tables in single query (you need to use transactions)
2. you can try something like this

> ```
> Begin Tran
>
> update Patient_Record 
> set b_ID = b.b_ID from bed b where b.Status_Avai_Occ = 'Available'
> and Patient_Record.Admission_Type = 'In Patient'
>
> Update bed set Status_Avai_Occ='Occupied' where b_ID in (select b_ID from Patient_Record where Patient_Record.Admission_Type = 'In Patient')
> Commit Tran
> ```